# iterating over list with streams base of the length of another list

Tags: java, java-stream

I'd like to perform such action using streams:

```
List<String> listX = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<listY.size();i++){
            listX.add(String.format(ABC,i));
        }
```

so I have to iterate over a list using the length of another list and additionally use counter i. After all i'd like to return the new list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [IntStream.range](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) & [IntStream.mapToObj](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) methods. and don't operates variables out of lambda expression in stream api, that will resulting in [Thread Interference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html) or [Memory Consistency Errors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) in parallel stream.

```
List<String> listX = IntStream.range(0, listY.size())
                              .mapToObj(i -> String.format(ABC,i))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IntStream` to iterate using index of `listY` as shown below:

```
IntStream.range(0, listY.size()).forEach(i -> listX.add(String.format(ABC,i)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* also use `Collectors.mapping`, something like this:

```
 IntStream.range(0, listY.size())
          .collect(Collectors.mapping(i -> String.format(ABC,i), 
                      Collectors.toList()));
```